# how to use resources variable in ejGrid tamplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use resource varible in ejGrid template, filed here some code where I want to use another code.

The code currently in my application :

```
 <ej:Column HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, BU_TaskTemp_Label_Task %>" Template="
<a href='{{:TaskUrl}}' class='btn blue btn-circle btn-outline'>Tasks</a>" />
```

The code what I want to use :

```
<ej:Column HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, BU_TaskTemp_Label_Task %>" 
Template="<a href='{{:TaskUrl}}' class='btn blue btn-circle btn-outline'>
<%$ Resources:Resource, BU_TaskTemp_Label_Task %></a>" />
```

hope you give me an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with the use of this code`<ej:Column HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, BU_TaskTemp_Label_Task %>" Template="#buttonTask" />` and the render file code`<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="buttonTask">
        <a href='{{:TaskUrl}}' class='btn blue btn-circle btn-outline'><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal6" Text=" <%$ Resources:Resource, BU_TaskTemp_Label_Task %>"></asp:Literal></a>
    </script>`